# Browser - Desktop - Browser data channel

Tags: javascript, c++, comet, websocket

I have a part of functionality on desktop (C++), which can't be moved to the web. And the main part of all is on the web.

For example:

I have an opened notepad on my desktop. I push the button and it open the default browser and navigate to my site. My site is a simple text area. when a write some text in a browser, it automatically duplicates in a notepad, and synchronize from notepad to browser also.

What I need to do:

- create some connection Desktop-Browser(site) to provide my data protocol over
- call desktop application from browser and work with it (send/recv data)
- call browser (open web site) from desktop application and wotk with it (send/recv data)

Server-browser connection can be implemented via WebSockets or Comet(2).

What can be used on desktop? Simple socket connection? And can be used on server?

Comment: I would say that you basically make the notepad/server the same application. As soon as you receive something, update the notepad text; when you type something in the notepad, send it to the browser.

Comment: what is your server platform?

Comment: i'm just looking for a thin client and platform.
server is *nix based platform. must be Java or PHP.
But what about data channel provider? how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out this [Arduino Pusher client](https://github.com/krohling/ArduinoPusherClient) (I work for Pusher) which is includes C++ WebSocket functionality. This way:

- You have one think desktop client which uses this library and just manages the notepad and sending and receiving messages.
- You have a web server in any language you like (Java, PHP or anything else that you can make a REST call from) (see the [Pusher REST libraries](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_libraries)).
- You have a web app (which uses the [Pusher JavaScript library](http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries#js)) to receive realtime updates.
- Put all this together to synchronise the web and the notepad apps.

If you'd rather put together your own infrastructure then you're probably going to have to:

- Choose a [self-hosted realtime server](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide#self-hosted) preferably with WebSocket support for lower latency and faster realtime communication.
- Write a custom app for your notepad app (you may already have this).
- Define a way for the app to talk to the realtime server so updates can be pushed to the web client.
- Hopefully the realtime server comes with a good suite of libraries for different client technologies or works with well defined libraries such as [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js)